# finding all first consecutive prime factors and find max of that by Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, prime-factoring

Let

> 2|n, 3|n,..., p_i|n, p_ j|n,..., p_k|n
>
> p_i < p_ j< ... < p_k

where all primes up to p_i divide n and

> j > i+1

I want to write a code in Mathematica to find p_i and determine {2,3,5,...,p_i}.

thanks.

> B = {};
>
> n = 2^6 * 3^8 * 5^3 * 7^2 * 11 * 23 * 29;
>
> For[i = 1, i <= k, i++,
>
> If[Mod[n, Prime[i]] == 0, AppendTo[B, Prime[i]]
>
> If[Mod[n, Prime[i + 1]] > 0, Break[]]]];
>
> mep1= Max[B];
>
> B
>
> mep1

result is

> {2,3,5,7,11}
>
> 11

I would like to write the code instead of B to get B[n], since I need to draw the graph of mep1[n] for given n.

Comment: What have you tried so far ? It's all very well you having this desire to write a code, but even systems far more advanced than Mathematica struggle with our desires, they respond much better to programs.  Show us what you have done and we may be able to help.

Comment: @High Performance Mark: I added the code, but my code is fixed when I want to draw the graph, I want B as a function of n, if n had a special rule.

Comment: Why do you want to write a function like that if you can just use `FactorInteger` which is guaranteed to be faster and better-tested?

Comment: @nikie, FactorInteger gives all factors but i need only firs consecutive prime factors starting from 2 up to p_i, which p_{i+1} is not a factor of that number.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question and code correctly you want a list of prime factors of the integer `n` but only the initial part of that list which matches the initial part of the list of all prime numbers.

I'll first observe that what you've posted looks much more like C or one of its relatives than  like *Mathematica*.  In fact you don't seem to have used any of the power of *Mathematica's* in-built functions at all.  If you want to really use *Mathematica* you need to start familiarising yourself with these functions; if that doesn't appeal stick to C and its ilk, it's a fairly useful programming language.

The first step I'd take is to get the prime factors of `n` like this:

```
listOfFactors = Transpose[FactorInteger[n]][[1]]
```

Look at the documentation for the details of what `FactorInteger` returns; here I'm using transposition and part to get only the list of prime factors and to drop their coefficients. You may not notice the use of the `Part` function, the doubled square brackets are the usual notation.  Note also that I don't have *Mathematica* on this machine so my syntax may be a bit awry.

Next, you want only those elements of `listOfFactors` which match the corresponding elements in the list of all prime numbers.  Do this in two steps.  First, get the integers from 1 to `k` at which the two lists match:

```
matches = TakeWhile[Range[Length[listOfFactors]],(listOfFactors[[#]]==Prime[#])&]
```

and then

```
listOfFactors[[matches]]
```

I'll leave it to you to:

- assemble these fragments into the function you want;
- correct the syntactical errors I have made; and
- figured out exactly what is going on in each (sub-)expression.

I make no warranty that this approach is the best approach in any general sense, but it makes much better use of *Mathematica's*  intrinsic functionality than your own first try and will, I hope, point you towards better use of the system in future.

Comment: the second command you did, it gives empty set. I wrote the following code, but it takes long time.  B[n_] := Table[
  If[Mod[n, Prime[i + 1]] > 0, Prime[i], Prime[n]/2], {i, 1, n}];
mep1[n_] := Min[B[n]]

Comment: Thanks. How can I make it as a function of n.

Comment: If you are really having trouble assembling the snippets of code I've provided into a function you should (re-)read the Mathematica documentation, perhaps starting with the tutorial *Defining Functions*.